# How to edit the web.config file content using batch file script?

Tags: batch-file

Hi I have a requirement to edit the web.cofig file using batch file script before deployment to IIS server. below is my sample web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
    </staticContent>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="Default.htm"/>
        <add value="Default.asp"/>
        <add value="index.htm"/>
        <add value="index.html"/>
        <add value="iisstart.htm"/>
        <add value="index.aspx"/>
        <add value="default.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="version" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <!--<trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="20" mostRecent="true" localOnly="false"/>-->
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <location path="bi-aws-proxy.ashx">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Here I need to update the value of `<add key="version" value=""/>` with the parameter passed to batch file.

Ex: Input to the batch file is a number as shown in the figure below.
[image]

Then I want the output web.config file with the line edited as below.

```
<add key="version" value="1267"/>
```

I tried with the below code that I got on internet, but not working properly.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "param=%1"
echo %param%
set "INTEXTFILE=web.config"
set "OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt"
set "SEARCHTEXT=<add key="version" value=""/>"
set "REPLACETEXT="<add key="version" value="%param%"/>"

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('type "%INTEXTFILE%"') do (
    set "string=%%A"
    set "modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!"
    echo !modified!>>"%OUTTEXTFILE%"
)

del "%INTEXTFILE%"
rename "%OUTTEXTFILE%" "%INTEXTFILE%"
endlocal
```

So, any help on this is appreciated; If possible please provide snippet of code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trying to do this in `cmd.exe` shell script (batch) is not trivial. I would recommend using PowerShell instead.

Comment: Do you *have to* **edit** an existing web.config file?  It would be easier if you could take the input and then create or replace the entire file.

Comment: I do not see the point in using an automated method for this task. After all, it is one named file, one instance of the search string, and upon finishing can only be used on that file again, after running the script again without any parameter. It may make a little more sense if you were to replace anything between the **`=`** and **`/`** with **`"%~1"`** on any line matching whatever you determine to be the safest string pattern or regular expression.